# HTTPs connection by apache httpclient 4.4

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm pretty new to httpclient, but what I'm trying to do is get and post stuff from my local https server.  When I use browser to access this url, I need to manually accept and continue.  I'm pretty much using this [sample code](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java) provided by apache.  It is so in my editor

```
public class ClientCustomSSL {

   public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
      final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getDefault();
      // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
      final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf =
            new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,
                  new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null,
                  SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
      final CloseableHttpClient httpclient =
            HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
      try {

         final HttpGet httpget =
               new HttpGet("https://localhost:8443/portal/css/style.css");

         System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

         final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
         try {
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
         } finally {
            response.close();
         }
      } finally {
         httpclient.close();
      }
   }

}
```

However, I got below exception...

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:395)
   at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:354)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
   at com.vmware.vdi.installer.broker.ClientCustomSSL.main(ClientCustomSSL.java:67)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
   ... 21 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
   ... 27 more
```

Not sure what I need to do....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html) there is a solution about this subject.

One of the solution is updating the CACERT file in the your JRE_HOME/lib directory.For that you can look [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210).

And the other solution is overriding the check and accept an untrusted certificate.

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
       new X509TrustManager() {
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
          }

          public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

          public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

       }
    };
```